# Can I programmatically change styling within react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I am curious if it is possible to set a style in react native to a variable that is set based on the result of an API hit?

So for example

```
let textColor = 'fake-api-getcolor'

<text style={{color: textColor}}>Hello</text>
```

And then have that API endpoint connected to a backend CMS where I would allow the user to choose a color.

I am not sure if this would be possible because of the app build/compile process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You'll just treat it as any normal object and use it for your values or styling. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710153/1463174) for a complete explanation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I am pretty familiar with React but just trying to learn React Native so I think I am overthinking what is editable after compile...

Comment: @TravisJames yeah you probably are. All properties are runtime bindable so you don't have to think much of the compile time. Which is also what makes the hot reload functionality work so well.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally posible if you are fetching that value then setting the variable every time that is a change in the backend. I mean, yes, you can have computed values in the styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using state

```js
class AppComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    textColor: "red"
  }


  async changeColor() {
    const color = "blue" //Here you can fetch color from your api then call setState like below
    this.setState({
      textColor: color
    })
  }


  render() {
    const {
      textColor
    } = this.state;
    return <text style={{color: textColor}}>Hello</text>
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

set color in setState dynamically

```
this.state = {
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
}
```